# I need to get a script using cherrio (not get text)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am scrapping a page and I need to get a json from a script tag
the script tag seens like

```
<template data-type="json" data-varname="__STATE__"> 
<script>
{
 "someJson": here 
}
</script>    
</template>
```

I got the value with something like this using jquery in browser

```
 $('template[data-varname="__STATE__"]').content.children[0]
```

and i got the value with something like that on my node code

```
const listItems = await $('template[data-varname="__STATE__"]');
await fs.promises.writeFile('site.html', listItems.html())
```

but my return is only a script like this

```
   <script>
    {
     "someJson": here 
    }
    </script>
```

inside a html file but I would like to get the json and already be able to use

Comment: The HTML of the `template` element is the `script` element and its text node. If you just want the `script` element's text, use `listItems.text()` instead of `html()`

Comment: @HereticMonkey .text() and .html() return the same result in this case, I need a way to get the content of the script to transform into json

Comment: I would use [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822452/215552) then

Comment: You replace <script></script>

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted as follows

```
const listItems = await $('template[data-varname="__STATE__"]');
const scriptItem = await  listItems.html()
const removeScript = scriptItem.replace("<script>","").replace("</script>","")
const jsonFromScript = JSON.parse(removeScript)
```

However this is not a solution that I like, if anyone knows a more "correct" way to do it I would be grateful

Comment: "correct" way, `const jsonFromScript = JSON.parse($('template[data-varname="__STATE__"] script').children[0].data)` btw you dont need to await them lines, they dont return promises